# How to conjugate the verb in a sentence that starts with "I wish..."

Tags: tenses, subjunctive-mood

I generally find it hard to construct some sentences that start with "I wish, ..."

Example:

(Background:) Due to an incomplete technical documentation, we chose the wrong path, and ran into an unforeseen limitation. What's the correct way to state my frustration?

- I wish, the documentation *would warn* about that limitation.
- I wish, the documentation *had warned* about that limitation.
- I wish, the documentation *would have warned* about that limitation.
- I wish, the documentation *warned* about that limitation.
- I *would wish*, that the documentation *warns* about that limitation.
- ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, you shouldn't have a comma after *wish*. In written English it's generally incorrect to add a comma before *that* or in a place where *that* has been omitted, as in the previous sentences.

Either of these is correct:

> I wish the documentation warned about that limitation.
>
> I wish the documentation had warned about that limitation.

In either case, you need a subjunctive form (which is almost always identical to the past form) in the subordinate clause. The main clause with *wish* should remain in the present tense — saying *I would wish* is unnecessary.

(The only time that the subjunctive is not the same as the simple past is when the subject is 1st- or 3rd-person singular:

> I wish I were taller.
>
> I wish it were true.

And even this is slipping away, as many people now say *I wish I was taller.*)

Comment: Thanks for your great answer (also for the comma hint)! Is "would warn" and "would have warned" completely wrong, or is it acceptable for spoken English?

Comment: It's not completely wrong, but it's mostly unnecessary. I would avoid using *would* for this construction in written English, though in spoken English it would probably pass without most people noticing.

Comment: Whenever I encounter one of OP's *would* forms, I always assume it's a non-native speaker trying to replicate the verb inflections of their own language. As to whether including *had* makes any difference, I think an IT tutor complaining about different students *repeatedly* making mistakes because of poor documentation is more likely to omit *had*. Where only one (albeit possibly serious and / or extended) mistake occured, *had* seems more natural to me.

Comment: "*The only time that the subjunctive is not the same as the simple past is when the subject is I*": I wish this were true.

Comment: @Cerberus, touché. Updated.

Comment: @JSBangs: Hehe thanks. The point is that "to be" is the only verb remaining with an irregular past subjunctive / past simple, which, as you say, is visible only in the 1st and 3rd persons singular, because those past simple forms happen to stand out in the paradigm (as the other past simple forms are all "were").

Comment: @JSBangs: What does "It's not completely wrong" mean?